# JavaFX - MediaPlayer Not Working

Tags: java, audio, javafx, media-player

```
package main;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import java.io.File;
import javafx.scene.media.AudioClip;


public class Controller {
Media sound = new Media("mouseHover.mp3");
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

I'm trying to play the sound file, but the error I'm getting is "cannot resolve symbol play" and my IDE also says that "mediaPlayer" is never even used. Why is this? I'm pretty sure the path to my media is correct (I put it in the root file next to src).

Comment: Executable code must be in a method. Probably you should revisit some fundamentals of Java before attempting to use a framework like JavaFX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a class, you need to execute `mediaPlayer.play()` in your main function of the app.

```
public class Controller {
    Media sound = new Media("mouseHover.mp3");
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(sound);
    //Empty constructor
    public Controller()
    {
    }
}
```

In your main function of the app you play it like this :

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
       Controller ct = new Controller();
       ct.mediaPlayer.play();
}
```

Comment: It worked thank you! Wait to clarify, the reason my original code didn't work was because I was calling the mediaClass method when it was a class variable, rather than when it is an object, which isn't allowed correct?

Comment: Yes, as James_D said executable code needs to be in a method. If you want it to be in the class you can create a method and put it inside.